# activerecord model with 2 parent levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

A user can have many questions. Many users can participate on a question and provide multiple answers to the same question. Relation between users and questions seems to be working fine. Problem is with answers.

**model/user.rb**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
  has_many :answers
```

**model/question.rb**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :answers
```

**model/answer.rb**

```
  has_one :question
  has_one :user, :through => :question
```

Here is what I'm trying in the console:

```
irb(main):022:0> u1.questions.first.answers.create(answer: "foo1", order:1)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Answer Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."answer" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["answer", "foo1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "answers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "answer", "order", "question_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:04 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:04 UTC], ["answer", "foo1"], ["order", 1], ["question_id", 1]]
   (13.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Answer id: 6, created_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:04", updated_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:04", answer: "foo1", order: 1, user_id: nil, question_id: 1>
irb(main):023:0> u1.questions.first.answers.create(answer: "bar1", order:2)
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Answer Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."answer" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["answer", "bar1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "answers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "answer", "order", "question_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:04 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:04 UTC], ["answer", "bar1"], ["order", 2], ["question_id", 1]]
   (19.9ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Answer id: 7, created_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:04", updated_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:04", answer: "bar1", order: 2, user_id: nil, question_id: 1>
irb(main):024:0> u2.questions.first.answers.create(answer: "foo2", order:1)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  Answer Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."answer" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["answer", "foo2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "answers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "answer", "order", "question_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:04 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:04 UTC], ["answer", "foo2"], ["order", 1], ["question_id", 1]]
   (16.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Answer id: 8, created_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:04", updated_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:04", answer: "foo2", order: 1, user_id: nil, question_id: 1>
irb(main):025:0> u2.questions.first.answers.create(answer: "bar2", order:2)
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Answer Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."answer" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["answer", "bar2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "answers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "answer", "order", "question_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:05 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-31 19:31:05 UTC], ["answer", "bar2"], ["order", 2], ["question_id", 1]]
   (14.9ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Answer id: 9, created_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:05", updated_at: "2017-03-31 19:31:05", answer: "bar2", order: 2, user_id: nil, question_id: 1>
```

It's obvious something is wrong given the fact user_id is null, unless I specify. I expect user_id populated given the fact I'm creating it from a user object through a question.

```
irb(main):027:0* u1.questions.first.answers.count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 1]]
=> 4
```

As I can see here, it just filters by question_id. I expect to retrieve the answers from question_id AND user_id

Can this problem be fixed? Should I just do it in another way?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

As a summary, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
User.first.answers.where(question_id: 1)
```

Where the query looks like:

```
SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."user_id" = $1 AND "answers"."question_id" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["question_id", 1]]
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
User.first.questions.first.answers
```

And get the answers for user_id and question_id

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't an answer belong to a user. If I were to answer this question that answer would belong to me.

Comment: Yes, it needs to go down to a user, but through a Question. What I would like is to do user.questions.find(1).answers and this returns the answers for this question done by this specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `belongs_to` for `:user` and `:question` (instead of `has_one`) and set user manually to your answers from `current_user` in controller.

Comment: Now I have the following error: MethodError: undefined method `question' for #<Answer:0x00000002e7c280> when creating a new answer with the command in the original question.